# Android app can not login with Facebook if Facebook app is not exists on device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Android app can not login with Facebook if Facebook app is not exists on device. Otherwise if Facebook app is exists on my device android app can login with Facebook and getting users public info. I need to make app able to login for all circumtances.

Comment: The Facebook SDK does that only, in case the app is not installed it shows up a dialogue for login